# Why does QGIS crash when merging shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, error

This is a repeatable problem. I have created a shapefile using a csv. I am trying to merge it with an existing shapefile, both of which contain only points. (Using the Vector | Data Management | Merge Shapefiles option.) I have double-checked that the shapefile type is correct, and the coordinate reference system matches. As soon as I click OK to accept the result, the message appears "qgis.exe has stopped working" etc., the usual Windows crash message.
Things I have done to reslove this:
1. I have a friend who has the same software and the same project files (we are collaborating on this project). I sent him my original csv file with the new data in it, and he was able to successfully merge the files at his end. So I know that the csv file is OK.
2. Uninstalled and re-installed the program. Identical result, program crashes every time as soon as I go to accept the merging of the shapefiles.

Using Windows 7.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? If not, is there another way to bring new data into the project? I don't want to use the "Add Feature" option as it is too difficult to get the co-ordinates correct with just hovering over the map.

Comment: Are you exporting your CSV layer as a shapefile before doing the merge?  If not, try this first.  Always export you CSV as a shapefile and reopen the newly-created shapefile to work on, this solves a lot of headaches.

Comment: Are the points of the same dimensionality (2d, 3d, etc?)

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

**Add [.prj files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Shapefile_projection_format_.28.prj.29)** to define the projection of each shapefile or use **mmqgis merge.**

This is a [known bug](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5962) that affects QGIS since version 1.8 and 1.9.
It has been replicated on different operating systems.

There are two short-term solutions:

- Use mmqgis merge function: Plugins | mmqgis | Transfer | merge. This works regardless of projection information:

[image: mmqgis merge]

- Re-save the shapefiles that you want to merge, adding projection information .prj files associated with each shapefile. FTools method should now work.

The long term solution is to wait until this bug has been fixed, but this may take a while!

P.s. I've created a [folder of sample shapefiles](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15008199/qgis-bug-test.zip) to test these methods - please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Thank you Robin Lovelace, the mmqgis method worked perfectly. Thanks to the others too, however, I had already saved as a shapefile prior to attempting the merge.

Answer (score 1):

The merging is done by a batch file outside Qgis. This will not work with the temporary file created by the CSV import.

Save as shapefile is the best solution.

Qgis should not crash, but give a reasonable error message.

Answer (score 0):

try to shorten file names and repeat the process. it works in similar issue for me

Comment: This should probably be a comment, unless you want to flesh out the answer a little more.